# Using FitVids JQuery Plugin in Anglular 2 Component

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular, fitvids

I want to use FitVids JQuery Plugin in Angular 2 Component. I tried to add fitVids function in JQuery interface in jquery.d.ts file but I get error. I'm using typescript. Thank you all!

I used this [jquery.d.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) file found on GitHub. I modified it to:

```
[...]
    queue(queueName: string, callback: Function): JQuery;
    fitVids(selector?: any, opts?: any): JQuery;
}
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var fitVids: JQueryStatic;
```

The error I get is:

```
EXCEPTION: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Articolo!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: jQuery(...).fitVids is not a function
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows what you have tried. Please add the actuall error message. "I get error" is not very informative.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having comes from the difference between **compiletime** and **runtime**

By adding the `fitvids` to the `.d.ts` file you are correctly setting the **definition** of the method for **compiletime**

However at **runtime** your application is looking for an *implementation* of that definition but it can't find one.

You need to add the `.js` file for fitvids to your `index.html` page

```
<script src="path/to/fitvids.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @SnareChops for the answer, but I've already added it